# C# Filter duplicates from list according to two criteria

Tags: c#, linq, for-loop, duplicates, nested-loops

I want to filter duplicates from a list of objects of type `A` based on a function `IsDuplicate`.

```
class A
{
    public int p1;
    public List<int> p2;
    public bool IsDuplicate(A other) => p2.Sum() == other.p2.Sum();

    public List<A> GetDistinctA(List<A> objects)
    {
        List<A> results = new();
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.Count; i++)
        {
            bool duplicated = false;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < objects.Count; j++)
            {
                if (objects[i].IsDuplicate(objects[j]))
                {
                    duplicated = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (duplicated)
            {
                continue;
            }

            results.Add(objects[i]);
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

I can accomplish this with a nested for-loop.

New requirement is to deduplicate the list based on the same function `isDuplicate` but the winning element if there is a duplicate is the one with the higher value of property `p1`. Sorting `objects` by `p1` will work but I guess that is not the most performant solution.

I am aware of Linqs `GroupBy` and `Distinct` but I don't know how to use the function as comparison criterion rather than a property.

Comment: `Distinct` doesn't let you particularly select which member of a group of equal objects to select - after all, you said they were equal. You can use `GroupBy` with the custom `IEqualityComparer` to do this, or with a `IEqualityComparer` generator based on some lambda methods.

Answer (score 3):

You can group the items by the sum of `p2`, order the groups by `p1` in descending order, then take the first one from each group in order to remove the duplicates.

You can also make the method `static`, since it doesn't need instance data:

```
public static List<A> GetDistinctA(List<A> objects)
{
    return objects?
        .GroupBy(a => a.p2.Sum())
        .Select(a => a.OrderByDescending(x => x.p1).First())
        .ToList();
}
```

Example usage:

```
var items = new List<A>
{
    new A { p1 = 0, p2 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } }, // 15
    new A { p1 = 1, p2 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 } },       // 6
    new A { p1 = 2, p2 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 5 } },       // 8
    new A { p1 = 3, p2 = new List<int> { 14 } },
    new A { p1 = 4, p2 = new List<int> { 3 } },
    new A { p1 = 5, p2 = new List<int> { 1, 2 } },          // 3
    new A { p1 = 6, p2 = new List<int> { 2, 3, 4, 5 } },    // 14
    new A { p1 = 7, p2 = new List<int> { 6 } },
    new A { p1 = 8, p2 = new List<int> { 15 } },
    new A { p1 = 9, p2 = new List<int> { 1, 3, 4} },        // 8
    new A { p1 = 10, p2 = new List<int> { 15 } },
};

var results = A.GetDistinct(items);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", results.Select(a => a.p1)));
// Output: 10, 7, 9, 6, 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to store all duplicates in a separate list "duplicates" and then

```
p2.RemoveAll(duplicates);
```

The new method for getting a distinct list AND removing all duplicates:

```
public List<A> GetDistinctAndRemoveDuplicatesFromA(List<A> objects)
{
    List<A> results = new();
    List<A> duplicates = new();

    for (int i = 0; i < objects.Count; i++)
    {
        bool duplicated = false;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < objects.Count; j++)
        {
            if (objects[i].IsDuplicate(objects[j]))
            {
                duplicated = true;
                if(objects[i].p1 < objects[j].p1) duplicates.Add(objects[i]); // Higher p1 survives
                break;
            }
        }

        if (duplicated)
        {
            continue;
        }

        results.Add(objects[i]);
    }
    objects.RemoveAll(duplicates)
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a helper class to generate an `IEqualityComparer` based on passed in lambda functions, you can use any `IsDuplicate` method to compare objects, though this is less efficient since I used the same hashcode of `1` for every object to avoid a dependency on the contents of `IsDuplicate`. This allows you to use `GroupBy` to combine "equal" objects and then select the appropriate one using the new .Net Core `MaxBy` extension method. (If you don't have `MaxBy`, it is easy to implement yourself.)

(The method should be `static` since it doesn't depend on a particular instance.)

```
public static List<A> GetDistinctA(List<A> someAs)
    => someAs.GroupBy(a => a,
                      Make.LambdaEq<A>(a => 1,
                                       (a1,a2) => a1.IsDuplicate(a2)))
             .Select(ag => ag.MaxBy(a => a.p1))
             .ToList();
```

Here is the `Make` helper class:

```
public static class Make {
    public static IEqualityComparer<T> LambdaEq<T>(Func<T, int> hashCodeFn, Func<T, T, bool> equalsFn) => new LambdaEqualityComparer<T>(hashCodeFn, equalsFn);
    public static IEqualityComparer<T> LambdaEq<T>(T _, Func<T, int> hashCodeFn, Func<T, T, bool> equalsFn) => new LambdaEqualityComparer<T>(hashCodeFn, equalsFn);

    class LambdaEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> {
        private Func<T, int> hashCodeFn;
        private Func<T, T, bool> equalsFn;

        public LambdaEqualityComparer(Func<T, int> _hashCodeFn, Func<T, T, bool> _equalsFn) {
            //        if(_hashCodeFn == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(_hashCodeFn));
            //        if(_equalsFn == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(_equalsFn));
            hashCodeFn = _hashCodeFn;
            equalsFn = _equalsFn;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(T x) => hashCodeFn(x); // must be method to fulfill interface
        public bool Equals(T x, T y) => equalsFn(x, y); // must be method to fulfill interface
    }
}
```